# How to make query selector troughout multiple divs with jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, laravel-blade

I have a div with `id="overlay-templates"` and I want to make a query with jQuery that adds the class to the clicked `<li>` with the data-template :

This is my code :

```
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent" id="overlay-templates"> <!--this is my div-->
    {{-- tabpanel-1 --}}
    <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="nav-test" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-test-tab">
        
        {{-- overlays-layouts-container --}}
        <div class="overlays-layouts-container">
            <div class="overlays-layouts-content">

                <div class="overlays-custom-colors-header">
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <p class="overlay-steps-p">Select a layout to customize from our overlay’s library</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <ul>
                    @foreach($overlayTemplates as $template)
                        @if($template->type == 1)

                            <!--here (li) where I want to add class named 'selected'-->
                                  <li 
                                    data-template="{{$template['id']}}"
                                    data-headercustomtext1 = "{{($template['header_text_1'] === 'dealer_phone') ? $phone : $template['header_text_1']}}"
                                    data-headercustomtext2 = "{{($template['header_text_2'] === 'dealer_website') ? $website : $template['header_text_2']}}"

                                    data-footercustomtext1 = "{{($template['footer_text_1'] === 'dealer_phone') ? $phone : $template['footer_text_1'] }}"
                                    data-footercustomtext2 = "{{($template['footer_text_2'] === 'dealer_website') ? $website : $template['footer_text_2']}}"

                                    data-footercustomtext3 = "{{$template['footer_text_3']}}"

                            > 
                                <div class="overlay-layouts-item">
                                    <img src="{{$template['thumbnails_path']}}" alt="">
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        {{-- end overlays-layouts-container --}}
    </div>
    {{-- end-tabpanel 1--}}
....
```

this jQuery code doesn't work for me :

```
            $('#overlay-templates > li[data-template="1"]')
                .addClass('selected');
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: Hi, remove `>` from your selector and see if that works .

Comment: Does you jquery in the code have the .click() handler?

Comment: I did, but it also doesn't work

Comment: there are two ids inside your div i.e:`id="nav-tabContent" id="overlay-templates"` remove `id="nav-tabContent"` and try again.

Comment: `$('#overlay-templates').find('li[data-template]').on('click', e => {
   $(e.currentTarget).addClass('selected')
 })`

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work !! I tried your code

Comment: Working just fine check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/a2onm3kz/) .

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments, I checked external file that contains the click event that I did'nt know because it's not my own code, I removed from there the `>` and it woked.

Answer (score 2):

You don't understand correct how is working css-selector `parent > child`, the fact is that this selector gets only direct child of parent element.
Actually it means that Elements which are not directly a child of the specified parent, are not selected.

For example

```css
#parent-block > .child {color:red;}
```

```html
<div id="parent-block">
<div class="child">Direct child</div>
<div class="child">Direct child</div>
<div class="child">Direct child</div>
<div class="some-wrap">
<div class="child">indirect child</div>
<div class="child">indirect child</div>
<div class="child">indirect child</div>
</div>
</div>
```

For your case you need to change your selector from `#overlay-templates > li[data-template="1"]` to `#overlay-templates ul > li[data-template="1"]`

And if you want to bind all click events for `li[data-template]` you just need to do like that

```
$('#overlay-templates ul > li[data-template]').click(function(e) {
...
})
```